# How to disable font scaling ( dynamic types from accessibility) for text inputs in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

How to disable font scaling (dynamic types - accessibility) for  text inputs in react native?

I have disabled dynamic types for text in the app by adding this code, but I still see that font in TextInputs are scaling:

```
 Text.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {}; //Disable dynamic type in IOS
 Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
```

Comment: why would you disable font scaling? Only wondering as you tagged this 'accessibility' and font scaling is one of the most important features.

Comment: Well, if user change in the accessibility settings, font to be 200% bigger than the original one, it will break a lot of UI.

Comment: I understand why you are doing it, just saying for accessibility you should design a UI to handle that in the first place, was just questioning the tag that is all as an accessibility answer would be 'do not interfere with important features designed for people with low vision, scaling font size is critical for some users'. Could you remove the tag as it is 'anti-accessibility' please, glad you fixed your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution, it can be done the same way as it was done with `Text`:

```
TextInput.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {}; //Disable dynamic type in IOS
TextInput.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
```

Comment: The same solution is complaining about default props not available in typescript. Any turnaround for that?